# MySQL grouping problem

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a sports tracker MySQL database and am trying to extract some stats; relevant tables are outlined below:

### game

id               bigint(20) unsigned PK
round_id         bigint(20)
team_1_id        bigint(20) unsigned
team_2_id        bigint(20) unsigned
date             datetime

### team

id               bigint(20) unsigned PK
name             varchar(128)

### player (not really required for this query)

id               bigint(20) unsigned PK
first_name       varchar(128)
surname          varchar(128)
dob              datetime

### player_team_game

id               bigint(20) unsigned PK
game_id          bigint(20) unsigned
player_id        bigint(20) unsigned
team_id          bigint(20)

### stats

id               bigint(20) PK
player_team_game_id bigint(20)
kicks            int(11)
goals            int(11)
tackles          int(11)

The intent is to determine total kicks, goals and tackles for each team in each game. An example resultset might look like the following:

```
game.id    | game.date    | team.name    | stats.kicks    | stats.goals    | stats.tackles  
1          | 2011-01-01   | team1        | 25             | 30             | 35  
1          | 2011-01-01   | team2        | 26             | 31             | 36  
2          | 2011-01-01   | team3        | 27             | 32             | 37  
2          | 2011-01-01   | team4        | 28             | 33             | 38  
3          | 2011-01-02   | team5        | 29             | 34             | 39  
3          | 2011-01-02   | team6        | 30             | 35             | 40
```

Can anyone help me with an appropriate query?

**Edit:** potentially I haven't made the problem clear; the issue is that the game table has both game.team_id_1 and game.team_id_2 so grouping needs to reflect the results for each team in separate recordsets.

Comment: Out of curiosity - did the SQL in my answer work for you without any modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    g.id, g.date,
    t.name,
    SUM(s.kicks),
    SUM(s.goals), 
    SUM(s.tackles)
FROM stats s
LEFT JOIN player_team_game ptg ON ptg.id = s.player_team_game_id
LEFT JOIN game g ON g.id = ptg.game_id
LEFT JOIN team t ON t.id = ptg.team_id
GROUP BY ptg.team_id
ORDER BY g.id, t.id
```

Comment: Not quite; firstly, grouping by player_team_game will give the player's totals for a game, not the team's. Also, the real problem is that grouping by team.id and game.id don't separate out the results for game.team_1_id and game.team_2_id. Potentially my question didn't make this clear; I'll add more detail above.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think the first problem can easily be solved by changing the `GROUP BY` clause, and the second problem by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks Matt - this was very close. Grouping by ptg.game_id before ptg.team_id grouped the stats by game as well as team which was the desired result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the below should give the result that you want.

```
select game.id, game.date, team.name, 
sum (stats.kicks), sum (stats.goals), sum (stats.tackles)
from game, player_team_game, stats, team
where player_team_game.game_id = game.id
and player_team.game.team_id = team.id
and player_team_game.id = stats.player_team_game_id
group by game.id, game.date, team.name
```